# database host in ipv6

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

I am configuring my django app that is to run from a VM instance in the google compute engine. The database exists in a google cloud sql instance whose ipv6 address I have. How can I mention this ipv6 address as the database's host in my app's settings.py?

The following doesn't work;

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '2001:4860:4864:1:a454:abcd:abcd:abcd',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

I end up with an error telling :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '2001:4860:4864:1:a454:abcd:abcd:abcd' (101)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Managed VM do not support IPv6. You will need to use the CloudSQL IPv4 address.

Comment: That is sad. Thanks though!